# In what contexts are arrays not turned into pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> An array reference (that is, any mention of an array **in a value context**), turns into a pointer.
>
> — [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrkindofary.html)

Is there a program (that compiles) where if you substitute an array value by a pointer value you get different behavior?

Let "different behavior" mean a different computed result, not how any compiler will compile the code differently to give the same result or how one will compile while the other not.

Comment: An example: the `sizeof` operator behaves differently.

Comment: Another example: you can't apply `++` to an array, but you can to a pointer of course.

Comment: try playing with a `2d int array` and a `pointer to pointer to int`. The 2 behave in a very different way. Co-coincidently me and my colleague were discussing this very issue from 2 days, and have settled on a satisfying result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array reference turns to pointer except when it is an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&` operator.

Comment: So you're saying array does not turn into a pointer in `a++` or `a =` either

Comment: @MattMcNabb; I didn't said about that. I said *array names are non-modifiable l-values* unlike pointers.

Comment: You were unclear about whether or not it turns into a pointer in those cases

Comment: @MattMcNabb; Removed that part. I am not sure about that.

Comment: @haccks: Just in case you're interested: They decay for both `++` and `=`. Lvalue conversion results in a non-lvalue, so the constraints for these operators (requiring lvalues as their (left) operands) are violated.

Comment: @mafso; Thanks for the information. It would be appreciated if you can quote from standard in favour of what you said :)

Comment: Sigh. C11 (n1570) 6.3.2.1 p3, 6.5.2.4 p1, 6.5.3.1 p3, 6.5.16 p2.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer might not point to a valid memory location (e.g. it may be a NULL pointer). This cannot happen for an array.

Comment: and this is a reason for liking programming languages (mostly).  You meant _might not_ while I read it first as _can not_.  The wonders of ambiguous languages eh?

Comment: You are right - I'm not a native english speaker. I corrected it.

Comment: I was being humorous.  Your original text was correct but ambiguous, as English often is.  Your correction is spot on and unambiguous.